# CouchDB won't start, no specific error

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

When trying to start as a service on Ubuntu 12.04.4, I get:

```
$ sudo service couchdb start
 * Starting database server couchdb                                      [fail]
```

Nothing in `/usr/local/var/log/couchdb`, nothing in `syslog` or `dmesg`.  I have no idea why it won't load. How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Isn't there an erlang generated logfile ?

Comment: If there is, I don't know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running CouchDB directly without init. Based on where you log files live, I'll assume you need to run:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/couchdb
```

Here are some scenarios:

- If it executes fine, then the sole bug is located in your init script.
- If it executes with an error, then you have an issue with your install **and** your init script is buggy (it should be giving you the error).
- If it doesn't execute at all (no output), then you've got a very broken install and we can debug that.

Comment: Running it manually works fine. But how do I figure out what's wrong with the `/etc/init.d/couchdb` file?

Comment: Ok, one problem was that couchdb user had a shell of `/usr/sbin/nologin`. I changed it to `/bin/sh`. But now starting the service does odd things. The server doesn't appear to be running, yet the couchdb.pid file changes every few seconds. VERY odd.

Comment: Sounds like there's a permissions problem. Have you followed these steps for Unix security? https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/INSTALL.Unix#L202